# C++ Passing an object by reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have a class that represents an capture zone in a game. Inside of this class I have a vector of player's that are capturing that zone (CUtlVector is a vector class from the SDK I am using)

```
typedef CUtlVector<ConquestPlayer*> CappingPlayersType; (defined outside of class)
CappingPlayersType CapturePlayers;
```

In my GameManager class, I am trying to retrieve the list of player's capturing using this code.

```
void GameManager::UpdateCaptureData()
{
    // Loop Active Capture Points
    for(int i = 0; i < CaptureZones.Count(); i++)
    {
        // Get List of Active Players Capturing this Point
        CappingPlayersType *CapturePlayers = NULL;
        int CapPlayersCount = CaptureZones.Element(i)->GetPlayersCapturing(CapturePlayers);


int CTriggerCaptureZone::GetPlayersCapturing(CappingPlayersType &CapPlayers)
{
    CapPlayers = CapturePlayers;

    return CapturePlayers.Count();
}
```

It has been a while though and I can't remember the best way to retrieve the list from the function and store it in a local variable. IIRC I can't pass by reference since the CapturePlayers object is NULL, but I am at a loss. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your code is kind of confusing. It seems as though you're always passing in a null pointer to the GetPlayersCapturing function, and then trying to coerce it to a reference. Can you explain in any more detail what you're trying to do, and why CapturePlayers is always NULL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
const CappingPlayersType& CTriggerCaptureZone::GetPlayersCapturing() const
{
    return CapturePlayers;
}
```

And in the calling function:

```
const CappingPlayersType& CapturePlayers = CaptureZones.Element(i)->GetPlayersCapturing();
size_t CapPlayersCount = CapturePlayers.size();
```

I haven't looked too carefully at the rest of the code (just trying to fit in with what you have), but it seems like you might just be wanting to return the internal `CUtlVector` by const reference.

Comment: I *think* he wants it to take in an argument, mutate that argument, and then return an integer, which is why he wanted to pass in a pointer.

Comment: @Cam: He might *want* to do that, but should he?

Comment: @Stuart: I don't think so. In particular I don't see why he has to return the count when `.Count()` is a member function of CapPlayers anyway. It's hard to tell given the limited context he's shown us though, but I think this answer is on the right track. Have a +1.

Comment: My gut feel is that a function called `GetPlayersCapturing` should return the *players* doing the capturing -- not how many of them there are. But call me old-fashioned... :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to pass in CapturePlayers, and have GetPlayersCapturing take care of initializing it.

You have two options:

1. You could make CapturePlayers a pointer, and accept it as a pointer in GetPlayersCapturing. You would set it to NULL, pass it in, and GetPlayersCapturing would allocate memory for it / initialize it.
2. You could declare CapturePlayers as a local variable like this:

   ```
   CappingPlayersType CapturePlayers;
   ```

   Then you could accept it as a reference in GetPlayersCapturing, which would modify it before returning the count.

Ultimately which of these you choose is up to you and it depends on more context than you've shown here. However I strongly recommend option 2, simply for the reason that you should avoid dealing with pointers whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you're doing after the GetPlayersCapturing() call, but I think overloading one call by returning both the count AND a reference to the real data is just going to trip you up unless you want to go work with raw pointers.

Why not have one function return the count, one function return a reference, and call them one after the other? No need to pass bad data, pre-initialize, or waste further time on it.